# Firebase deployment error using node 12 in vscode

Tags: node.js, firebase, visual-studio-code

I am trying to deploy a firebase project (functions/hosting) and in my functions package.json, I changed the engine to node 12 because some of my other packages required it to be at least node 12 (previously it was node 10).

When I try and deploy using vscode, I get this error:

```
Error: package.json in functions directory has an engines field which is unsupported. The only valid choices are: {"node": "8"} and {"node": "10"}. Note that Node.js 6 is now deprecated.
```

After spending a few hours trying to get this to work, I was able to deploy from my terminal using `firebase deploy`, but it's still throwing the same error when I try and deploy directly from vscode. From the firebase documentation it seems like node 12 should be available? https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version
I also ran `npm install -g firebase-tools` to update my firebase tools.

From the log of the failure, I am using:

```
2 info using npm@6.14.16
3 info using node@v12.22.12
```

Comment: Can you include `package.json`? Try removing the `"engines"` section.

Answer (score 1):

If the package.json file in your functions dir has :

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  }
```

Then you are fine.

Firebase supports up to Node 16.

It sounds to me like your VS Code environment has a different version of node installed than your terminal - which could also mean that you have a different (older) version of firebase-tools being used by VS Code.

To test this just run this in both your terminal and VS Code and compare the results :

```
node --version
```

Comment: my vs code has node 12, I tried that - I think it might have to something to do with the vs code not having the updated firebase tools, but I'm not sure how

Comment: When you say 'deploy directly from vscode' do you mean from the integrated terminal - or how?

One solution would be to create a new npm script to deploy.